# Using BLE chips to connect devices among them and to a smartphone

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

My question is not related to the software, but to the technology. I think BLE is the solution to my system, but I am not sure how it works, how the pairing works.

I am projecting a system with 4 devices, each one with some sensors.
Devices A1 and A2 have same sensors, they are independent each other and read different data. If one of them read a critical value, it makes a noise.

Devices B1 and B2 have same sensors, they are close and are dependent each other. I mean, I need to know if the value of B1 is higher than B2 or viceversa. The device with the higher value makes a noise.

```
----         ------------           ----
|A1| ------> |smartphone |  <-----  |B1| <--|
----          ------------          ----    |
                ^     ^                     |
----            |     |             ----    |
|A2|  ----------|     |-----------  |B2| <--|
----                                ----
```

These devices are all close by each other, and will synchronize later, just at the end of the day, to a smartphone to store  all the data read.

How can I make the connectivity among sensors and smartphone?
I need to make communicate B1 and B2, to know who has the higher value.
Then I need to make communicate all of them to a smartphone to collect data.

Is one chip Bluetooth Low Energy for each device enough ? Can I use the same chip to communicate between devices, and with the smartphone (in different moments) ?

I am not sure about the pairing process... should I need to associate and disassociate devices to the smartphone each time?  Or it's better to have B1 as master with 2 chips BLE, one for the smartphone and one to communicate do B2?

Answer (score 2):

BLE requires that one device be a server, the other the client, in order to establish a connection.  You cannot have a server talk to a server, or a client talk to a client.  However, devices can implement both server and client protocols.

If B1 and B2 are identical, and they only implement either server or client interfaces, then they cannot talk to each other.  If you have design control over B1 and B2, you can design them to implement both server and client protocols and then automatically talk to each other to update each one on who has the higher value.  However, I wonder why you need to have them talk to each other at all - why can't the smartphone get both B1 and B2 values, then decide which to keep?  It could then also send a command to B1 or B2 to make the noise.

A single BLE chip can manage many connections, since BLE connections are very temporary (and, if the internal software supports it, it may be able to handle multiple simultaneous connections).

If the decision about which I would have B1 and B2 simply include their measurement data in their advertising packet, and then have both listen to the others advertising packets.  In this case, there is no need to establish any negotiated connection at all - each device is just running a BLE "nearby devices" scan continuously.  Then, when the smartphone comes by, they can each establish a negotiated connection with the phone independently and upload their data.

Comment: In my system, the devices should be able to operate independently from the phone. I would use the smartphone just to download the data, and show some graphics and statistics.   I didn't get the second part of you answer. Do you mean....  they can broadcast their advertising packets, with the measurement data, so also the other can read without establish a connection, right?  But then, how can I connect to the phone to stream all the data stored? Can I easily switch between "broadcast iBeacon like" and "establish a connection to stream the data" ?

Comment: I won't make a judgement about how "easily" you can switch between the two modes, but yes, it can be done.  You may have to pause advertising while downloading data, but I suspect that there is a way to make it work.  The first google hit for "can BLE advertise while connected" indicates that it's not common, but can be done.

Comment: thank you. Do you think that using two BLE chips could be a more common solution? Theoretically, I have design control, but I would avoid atypical solution.

Comment: I don't have enough design experience on this type of problem to answer your question.  I hope my answer has been helpful to you.